# Python 3 List Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still on the process of learning python and recently I started working on a scrip where I created this very long list:

```
non = ["Hello","Hey","Hi","Greetings","My","Ok","You","He","She","It",
       "They","Our","Mine","Your","Tomorow","Today","If","For"]
print(non)
```

When I try to run the script it gives me a syntax error on the item "They".

```
**"The**y",
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/h9UQvh) Check for weird Unicode characters or discrepancies between the code you ran and the code you posted.

Comment: Also check the indentation before "They"

Answer (score -1):

@Fargo...if you run the script in this format it will give you a multiline error the proper way to write the code is given in the image link...hope it wiil be useful ...
and here is your output -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqPMH.png